# How to build a dataframe from a column with lists defining the column index with the envelope of the elements of the list as column indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I hope the example shows what I need. This is the input dataframe:

```
dic={'a': [[1,2,3,5,8]], 'b': [[4,3,5,8]], 'c': [[4,3]]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic,orient='index')

                 0
a  [1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
b     [4, 3, 5, 8]
c           [4, 3]
```

And this is the dataframe I would like to get:

```
df2=pd.DataFrame({1:[True,False,False], 2:[True,False,False], 3:[True,True,True], 4:[False,True,True], 5:[True,True,False], 8:[True,True,False]}, index=['a', 'b', 'c'])

       1      2     3      4      5      8
a   True   True  True  False   True   True
b  False  False  True   True   True   True
c  False  False  True   True  False  False
```

Later on I have to idenfy the groups of identical columns (for example 1 and 2, and 5 and 8).

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Try with `explode` and `crosstab`:

```
s = df[0].explode()
pd.crosstab(s.index, s.values).astype(bool)
```

Output:

```
col_0      1      2     3      4      5      8
row_0                                         
a       True   True  True  False   True   True
b      False  False  True   True   True   True
c      False  False  True   True  False  False
```